# CSS Grid Layout: Overlapping in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, grid-layout, css-grid

There are quite a few grid problems with IE11 (of course), but I have not seen this one yet.

The issue is simple, instead of showing the grid items nearby each other, they are displayed on top of each other, as if they were positioned absolute?

Here is the example:
https://dev.meteo.cam/detail

This is how it looks in modern browsers:
[image]

This is how it looks in IE11 :(
[image]
(If you select the elements in the inspector, you'll see that the weather image box is overlapped by the weather data box)

This is the CSS code:

```
.layout-grid {
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap:2em;
    padding: 2em;
}
.layout-grid-5050 {
    -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but not really helpful since I used the exact syntax from that example actually...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the answer from @xxxmatko and added a surrounding 2em gap.

```
.layout-grid {
  display: flex;
  padding-top:2em;
  padding-left:2em;
}

.layout-grid > .box {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  margin-right:2em;
  margin-bottom:2em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your css and use flex, like this:

```
.layout-grid {
   display: flex;
}

.layout-grid > .box {
   flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: Well, in general this makes sense. But I want to have the gap in between. The space around should be equal to the space between the boxes. So how would it look best? Also in mobile, it should have only 1 column.